# How to secure the android assets folder from hackers

Tags: android, assets

How can I protect the Android assets folder from hackers. Is there any method to safeguard the assets folder?

Answer (score 6):

Anything you save in **Asset** folder is accessible only after you copy it in internal or external cache directory. So there's no way you may keep it safe from exploiters at the same time too. However, you may save anything in this folder as encrypted and decrypt it at run-time just before using it.

Comment: @Raj: More generally, if the data is on the device, anyone with root access can get to it, no matter where it resides. If you do not want rooted device users to get at the data, do not put it on the device, but download it only as needed.