# Protecting code in android asset files

Tags: android, security, webview, assets

I have an android application which takes place mostly in webview, I have my html files in my assets folder, but files in the assets folder are very fragile and anyone can have access to codes in assets files. I wanted to ask if you have any tips to protect html and js files in android assets folder.
Thanks very much

Comment: Hope this helps   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406581/security-of-android-assets-folder        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683346/how-to-secure-the-android-assets-folder-from-hackers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my personal suggestion for the security about asset folder.

- You can load your html or js files from server to webview in runtime.
- Encrypt your html or js files, the encrypt/decrypt keys are stored in the server, when you app run, get the decrypt key from the server to decrypt your html or js files, then render in the webview.